# Chromecast - How to reconnect to the session after page refresh?

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast

After reloading the page, method

```
cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance()
```

returns status 'NOT_CONNECTED' and 'NO_SESSION'

My code example:

```
const castContext = window.cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance();

castContext.setOptions({
  receiverApplicationId:
    window.chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID,
  autoJoinPolicy: window.chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.ORIGIN_SCOPED,
  resumeSavedSession: true
});

await castContext.requestSession(); // wait for prompt

const castSession = castContext.getCurrentSession();

const mediaInfo = new window.chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(mediaUrl);

const request = new window.chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);

await castSession.loadMedia(request);

window.player = new window.cast.framework.RemotePlayer();

window.playerController = new window.cast.framework.RemotePlayerController(
window.player);
```

Can you please tell me how to connect to an existing session and receive information about playing media?

Comment: Hm. Session will restored if you switch port in the webpack settings. I switched it from 3000 to 8080. I'm in a mess :)

Comment: Did the answer below fix it? Have you found a(nother) solution?

Answer (score 0):

I been looking around for answers for a while and your switch of port make me think.

1. Switching port not a valid solution!
2. Why does a solution suddenly stop working without any changes to my Chromecast code?

**Answer**: Chrome got the hiccups. I guess this is either because of several live-refresh or something went wrong during development and it has been cached?!

**Solution**: I cleared the application storage and deleted my Chrome profile. After a restart of Chrome my solution reconnects with the chromecast as it did before.

[image]